# What is wrong with this edit?

Tags: support

I made an [edit suggestion](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9083) on this [question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/poland-work-permit-application-by-employer) and it was rejected by a mod with the reason

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

However my suggestion was mainly about retagging from [india](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) to [indian-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-citizens) as the question was *not* about living in India as an expatriate but about citizens of India (trying to apply for Poland). Hence it does make the question *easier to find*. While I was on it, I also removed some noise from the question.

Or have I got it backwards? Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with the edit so that I can improve my edits in the future?

Comment: Glad you've got and accepted the answer below. It's nice to see when people querying edit rejections in a calm and reasoned manner - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what happened here. The retagging from [india](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) to [indian-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-citizens) was correct. Given you were retagging the question, removing the *thanks* part makes sense since the question would already get bumped to the front page from the tag edit.

The timeline on the question is confusing to me. You edited the question while it was still open. When the review was completed and the edit rejected, the question was either closed (or close to closed). For closed questions, it is generally desirable for edits to address the reason the question is closed. In this case it all crossed in the wind.

There is also the possibility that the reviewer simply missed the retagging of the question. The reject reason is from a standard tick box (I believe) and sounds harsher than is intended. I wouldn't worry about the rejection. Keep making edits and improving the site.

The OP has since revised the question and I voted to reopen it (along with making your suggested edits). I apologize for stealing your 2 points of rep :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah it probably looks like a mix up now that you have explained. Thanks for applying my edit.

Answer (score 2):

the rejection is from me, and as others have raised the possibility: I unfortunately missed the retag, and only saw the removal of the thanks part, which on it's own would not have been a major edit,  especially in a long text, which might have also been improved a bit while there.

Also note that retag-only edits need much less reputation, which you already have, meaning you can easily retag questions if you wish.

Comment: I agree I could have edited the question a bit more and that would have been a good edit. I will try to improve my future edits. Thank you for clarifying.